# Variable Multiplication in C?

Tags: c, variables, constants, multiplication

```
//Hydroelectric Dam Helper
#include <stdio.h>
#define GRAV 9.80
#define EFINC 0.9
#define EFINC2 90


int main()
{
  //Defines all the variables to be used
  double height, work, mass;
  printf("Height of dam (in meters):");
  scanf("%lf", &height);
  printf("Flow of water (in thousand cubic meters per second):");
  scanf("%lf", &mass);
  work = (mass * GRAV * height * EFINC); 
  printf("The dam would produce %f megawatts at %d%% efficency", &work, EFINC2);
  return 0; 
}
```

The values set correctly, I tested it by having it print height and mass but work never receives a value, and EFINC2 prints out a ridiculous number that I'm not really sure about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
printf("The dam would produce %f megawatts at %d%% efficency", &work, EFINC2);
```

should read:

```
printf("The dam would produce %f megawatts at %d%% efficency", work, EFINC2);
```

`&work` is a pointer to work, i.e. a `double*` but for `printf` to print the value you need to pass a `double` and not a pointer. On your platform a `double*` is probably a different size to a `double` causing the subsequent `printf` formats to use the wrong data.

Comment: It is easy to think what is printed on the console is the variables value .....to be safe always check the actual variable in the debugger.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are having printf output a `float` with the `%f` specifier but passing in a `double*` via `&work`.  Just remove the `&` and it should work fine.

```
printf("The dam would produce %f megawatts at %d%% efficency", work, EFINC2);
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you are receiving a "ridiculous number" is that you are passing the address of `work` to `printf()`. Change `&work` to `work` and it should work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. The ampersand `&` in the printf-line means that the **address** of the variable `work` is read instead of the **value**

Answer (score 1):

Try appending a d to the constants to force c to not cast to int might work. You could also try explicitly casting the values to either float or double.

Answer (score 0):

you have given &work which is the address of work variable in memory, so it doesn't print any absurd value, it prints the memory location of work.

You should remove & from &work to receive value of work variable.

printf("The dam would produce %f megawatts at %d%% efficency", work, EFINC2);